# How to use CATIA CatScript macro to capture a specific view of a part?

Tags: macros, capture, catia

I am tasked to find a way to help our design team to screen capture a specific position of a part. However, I don't know how to customize my own position.

I tried looking at some codes on the internet and I found this:

```
Sub CATMain()
 
Dim productDocument1 As Document
Set productDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Dim cameras1 As Cameras
Set cameras1 = productDocument1.Cameras
Dim camera3D1 As Camera
Set camera3D1 = cameras1.Item(1)
Dim viewpoint3D1 As Viewpoint3D
Set viewpoint3D1 = camera3D1.Viewpoint3D
Dim specsAndGeomWindow1 As Window
Set specsAndGeomWindow1 = CATIA.ActiveWindow
Dim viewer3D1 As Viewer
Set viewer3D1 = specsAndGeomWindow1.ActiveViewer
viewer3D1.Viewpoint3D = viewpoint3D1
Set viewpoint3D1 = camera3D1.Viewpoint3D
viewer3D1.Viewpoint3D = viewpoint3D1

Dim filelocation As String
filelocation = "c:\Temporary\"
Dim extension As String
extension = ".jpg"
Dim Name as string
Name= filelocation & "right" & extension
viewer3D1.Viewpoint3D =camera3D1.Viewpoint3D
CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Clear()
viewer3D1.Capturetofile 5,Name

Dim camera3D2 As Camera
Set camera3D2 = cameras1.Item(2)
Dim viewpoint3D2 As Viewpoint3D
Set viewpoint3D2 = camera3D2.Viewpoint3D
viewer3D1.Viewpoint3D = viewpoint3D2
Set viewpoint3D2 = camera3D2.Viewpoint3D
viewer3D1.Viewpoint3D = viewpoint3D2

Name = filelocation & "left" & extension
viewer3D1.Viewpoint3D =camera3D2.Viewpoint3D
CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Clear()
viewer3D1.Capturetofile 5,Name
End Sub
```

Is there a way to tweak this code in terms of my own position that I want?

Thank you!

Comment: What view you want to use? The cameras 1 to 7 are the predefined views (iso, front, ...).

Comment: Hi @Shrotter! I'm planning to use my own custom views. Meaning, I will position and zoom at the part myself and kinda 'save' that position for future use. I'm still new to programming macro in CATIA, don't really know the basics to be honest. I'm just trying my luck to try out this program and tweak it to make my own.

Comment: Please have a look on the method _NewCamera_ of the _Viewer_ object, which creates a new camera from the viewpoint of the viewer. (give the macro recorder a try)